# SharePoint 2013 Search number stemming

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I've got a list with a single line-field. In this field are product numbers like 701.25.898 and 701.334.445. I created a managed property from this field.

When using the search and searching for 01 I get two both results. When search for 25 I get no results. When searching for 89 there is no result.

Is there a possibility to stem the search for numbers? Or do something else to get the results for this partial query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe stemming is the answer as numbers would not have recognized stems like "run, runs and running". You could use "701*" for a free text wildcard search. I would also try creating a Managed Property out of your crawled property and then try a contains search "PartNumber:701". The Content Processor may also be performing word breaking on the "." in your part numbers which may be leading to some odd behavior. For example I would guess that a search for "701.25" would be the same as "701 25" (unless you are using Complete Matching.)

All in all, partial mating inside a string is not well supported in SharePoint beyond the suffix wildcard match.

Comment: I assumed this too but thanks for the validation.